# Filter by links and order by dropdowns on the same page with ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax

I'm new to this site, php and ajax.  I've tried searching for the solution but can only find partial of it.  Here's what I'm trying to do, I have a page with 2 links (Make, and Model) and 2 dropdowns (Sort By, and ASC/DESC).   When user click on the Make link, the page with refresh and display all cars by Make (i.e. all Toyotas).  If click on the Models, it will refresh the page showing all cars by Model (i.e. all Camrys).  And if the user also click on the Sort By (i.e. Year), it needs to show either Make/Model and sort by year.  And same goes with the ASC/DESC.  I found some sample codes from this site to do the Sort By part, but don't know how to make the other drop down and links to work.  Here's what i have so far... Please help!!  Thanks!

```
inventory.php

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeContent(strOrderBy, strMake)  
{  
    alert(strOrderBy + " " + strMake");
    if (strOrderBy=="")
    {
        // if blank, we'll set our innerHTML to be blank.
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        // create a new XML http Request that will go to our generator webpage.
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {  // code for IE6, IE5
        // create an activeX object
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    // on state change
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        // if we get a good response from the webpage, display the output
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    // use our XML HTTP Request object to send a get to our content php. 
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getinventory.php?orderby="+strOrderBy+"&make="+strMake, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<body>

    <div class="colrecNav4">Sort By:&nbsp;
        <select name="sort" id="sort" onchange="changeContent(this.value, ???)">
            <option value="year">Year</option>
            <option value="trim">Trim</option>
            <option value="price">Price</option>
            <option value="miles">Miles</option>
        </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="dir" id="dir" onchange="changeContent(this.value)">
            <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
            <option value="desc">Descending</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <?php
        //reading data from the database
        echo '<div class="makemodel"><a href="#" id="byMake">' . $makeFromDb . '</a></div>';
        echo '<div class="makemodel"><a href="#" id="byModel">' . $modelFromDb . '</a></div>';
    ?>
    <script>
    $(".makemodela").bind("click", function(event){
            var div_id=$(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'getinventory.php',
        success: function(data){
            changeContent($('#sort').val(), div_id);
        }
    });
    });
    </script>
....
</body>

getinventory.php 
<?php
...
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory ORDER BY " . $_REQUEST['orderby'];  
    $result = mysql_query($sql);  

    while (...) {
    echo "results...."
    }
?>
```

Experts:  So i added another parameter to the changeContent function, updated the code, now I can see the values from the alert message in the changeContent function when I click on the Make or Model links.  But I can only see it the first time.  After that, it doesn't do anything.  Could someone please help?  Thanks!

EDIT:
So my inventory.php page after the sortby dropdown

```
<?php
    $make_results = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM tblmake ORDER BY Make");
    foreach ($make_results as $make_result) {
        echo '<div class="makemodel"><a href="#" id="' . $make_result->Make . '">' . $make_result->Make . '</a></div>
    ....
    //similar for model link
?>
<script>
$(".makemodel a").bind("click", function(event){
        var div_id=$(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'getinventory.php',
            success: function(data){
                changeContent($('#sort').val(), div_id);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and my getinventory.php page

```
$orderby = $_REQUEST['orderby'];        
$make = $_REQUEST['make'];

    $search_results = $db->get_results("SELECT qry WHERE MAKE=" . $make . " ORDER BY " . $orderby)
    //display results
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At any onChange event, either sort by or sort column will be passed by your AJAX call. You need to pass both the parameters and on each change change, you need to check the value of other dropdown as well so that valid MySQL query can be built.

Like `ORDER BY year DESC`.

Comment: Ehs4n, thanks for your response.  Oops, I clicked the wrong button...instead of add comment, I clicked answer your question.  Anyway, I have a question regarding this.  How do I pass the other dropdown's parameter?  And do i need to add more arguments to the changeContent function?  Thanks!

Comment: Anyone have any other ideas?  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the change of value from drop down using ".change" function in jquery and pass

that value to the your getinventory.php using ajax and create a html page in

getinventory.php as depend upon on the value and include that result after sucess

check the code below

```
$("#dir").change(function(){

  var selectedValues = $("#sort").val();

  $.post("http://localhost/getinventory.php/orderby/"+selectedValues,function(data){

    $("#yourdiv").html(data); // Here data consits of the html page 

  });

});
```

Comment: I got the value of the other dropdown already.  I'm having problem with the links (make/model) only work for the first time after the page is loaded.  After that the links don't work any more.

Comment: @user1939137 can you show me how you included your (make/model) link and how you calling the destination